# Stuck in download when using Instaloader with Python

Tags: python, download, instagram

I was just getting started with [Instaloader](https://instaloader.github.io/as-module.html) but when i tried to download a specific post, my code wouldn't continue

```
from instaloader import Instaloader, Profile, Post

# Get instance
L = Instaloader()

L.login(username, password)
print("login complete")

post = Post.from_shortcode(L.context, "CEPH-B0M8B9")
L.download_post(post, target='test')
print("test")
```

It wouldn't print the "test"

And I was also having some difficulties changing the filename as which the post would get saved. [In the documentation](https://instaloader.github.io/module/instaloader.html?highlight=download#instaloader.Instaloader.download_post) it says:

> target (Union[str, Path]) – Target name, i.e. profile name, #hashtag,
> :feed; for filename.

but that wasn't helping me at all :/

I appreciate every answer :D

Comment: No errors are displayed? If any, please add them to your question.

Comment: No unfortunately no errors. The output:
login complete
test\2020-08-23_15-09-17_UTC.jpg [#HelloFrom Mount Bromo in Eas…] geo

I found the actual function on github: https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader/blob/master/instaloader/instaloader.py#LC501:~:text=def%20download_post(self%2C%20post%3A%20Post%2C%20target%3A%20Union%5Bstr%2C,return%20downloaded

And it seems like there are more arguments but I don't know how to use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the source code i found the problem.

The download_post function does a lot of stuff and you can deactivate them with these lines:

```
L = Instaloader()
L.post_metadata_txt_pattern = ""
L.download_geotags = False
L.save_metadata = False
L.save_metadata_json = False
L.download_comments = False
```

The issue why the code wouldn't continue was that the function just took forever to download all comments

Hope this will help and safe some time for someone in the future :)